# SharePoint 2013 cannot find content type of Report Server Integration Feature

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

I have a error when I trying to activate feature "Report Server Integration Feature" on my site collection. The message of the error is :

> The content type with Id 0x010100C3676CDFA2F24E1D949A8BF2B06F6B8B defined in feature {e8389ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite.

I tried to use this [this](http://www.andrewjbillings.com/sharepoint-2013ssrs-2014-error-activating-reporting-services-integration-feature/) solution but it didn't helped.

I found that report server feature has compatibilty level is 14. Can it be a root of this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. The problem was in ReportServer CompatibilityLevel 15. Solution I found in [enter link description here](http://outerbanks-deals.com/sb/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-ssrs-content-types-missing-patching/) article.

Fix:
Install-SPFeature -path “ReportServer” -CompatibilityLevel 15